# Generating output comment for 70000 rows

Tags: vba, excel

For traversing 70,000 rows (using a `for` loop), my macro is taking a lot of time to give output comment as per various conditions (`if` statement). Please help me improve my approach. I am working on around 70,000 rows and my code is taking a lot of time to run. Please see the attachment image that depicts how data looks.

[image]

```
Option Explicit
Sub Analysis()
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayStatusBar = False
ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Dim wsa As Worksheet
Dim l, AudLastRow, AudLastCol, NIMsLastCol, NIMsRow As Long
Dim d19, d8, d25, p19, p8, p25 As Integer
Dim ColLtr As String
Dim aPRTS, bNIMS, Deployed19, Deployed800, Deployed2500, PRTS800, PRTS1900, PRTS2500 As Variant

Set wsa = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Audit-NIMS vs Site Topology")
NIMsLastCol = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("NIMSCarrierCount").Cells(2, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
NIMsRow = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("NIMS dump-SC level").Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

With wsa
    AudLastCol = .Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    AudLastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    .Cells(1, AudLastCol + 1).Value = "Match;Issue Type;Actions"
    For l = 2 To AudLastRow
        aPRTS = .Cells(l, AudLastCol).Value
        bNIMS = .Cells(l, NIMsLastCol).Value
'        tempin = .Cells(l, 2).Value
        If aPRTS = bNIMS Then
            Deployed19 = Application.Match("Deployed(1.9)", .Rows(1), 0)
            If IsNumeric(Deployed19) Then
                d19 = .Cells(l, Deployed19).Value
            Else
                d19 = 0
            End If
            Deployed800 = Application.Match("Deployed (800)", .Rows(1), 0)
            If IsNumeric(Deployed800) Then
                d8 = .Cells(l, Deployed800).Value
            Else
                d8 = 0
            End If
            Deployed2500 = Application.Match("Deployed (2.5)", .Rows(1), 0)
            If IsNumeric(Deployed2500) Then
                d25 = .Cells(l, Deployed2500).Value
            Else
                d25 = 0
            End If

            PRTS800 = Application.Match("Total-800-PRTS", .Rows(1), 0)
            If IsNumeric(PRTS800) Then
                p8 = .Cells(l, PRTS800).Value
            Else
                p8 = 0
            End If

            PRTS1900 = Application.Match("Total-1900-PRTS", .Rows(1), 0)
            If IsNumeric(PRTS1900) Then
                p19 = .Cells(l, PRTS1900).Value
            Else
                p19 = 0
            End If

            PRTS2500 = Application.Match("Total-2500-PRTS", .Rows(1), 0)
            If IsNumeric(PRTS2500) Then
                p25 = .Cells(l, PRTS2500).Value
            Else
                p25 = 0
            End If
            If (p19 = d19) And (p8 = d8) And (p25 = d25) Then
                .Cells(l, AudLastCol + 1).Value = "TRUE;None;No Action Required."
            Else
                .Cells(l, AudLastCol + 1).Value = "FALSE;Both;Update NIMS and PRTS."
            End If
        ElseIf aPRTS = "NA" And bNIMS = "0" Then
            .Cells(l, AudLastCol + 1).Value = "TRUE;None;No Action Required."
        ElseIf aPRTS = "0" And bNIMS = "NA" Then
            .Cells(l, AudLastCol + 1).Value = "TRUE;None;No Action Required."
        ElseIf aPRTS > 0 And bNIMS = "NA" Then
            .Cells(l, AudLastCol + 1).Value = "N/A;NIMS;Update NIMS."
        ElseIf bNIMS > 0 And aPRTS = "NA" Then
            .Cells(l, AudLastCol + 1).Value = "N/A;PRTS;Check traffic from PRTS & Report to PRTS Team."
        ElseIf bNIMS > aPRTS Then
            .Cells(l, AudLastCol + 1).Value = "FALSE;PRTS;Check traffic from PRTS & Report to PRTS Team."
        ElseIf bNIMS < aPRTS Then
            .Cells(l, AudLastCol + 1).Value = "FALSE;NIMS;Update NIMS."
        End If

        If InStr(1, .Cells(l, 1).Value, "52XC") > 0 Then
            .Cells(l, AudLastCol + 1).Value = .Cells(l, AudLastCol + 1).Value & "Clearwire Site."
        ElseIf InStr(1, .Cells(l, 1).Value, "82XC") > 0 Then
            .Cells(l, AudLastCol + 1).Value = .Cells(l, AudLastCol + 1).Value & "Clearwire Site."
        ElseIf InStr(1, .Cells(l, 1).Value, "XT") > 0 Then
            .Cells(l, AudLastCol + 1).Value = .Cells(l, AudLastCol + 1).Value & "COW Site."
        End If

        If bNIMS = "NA" And Application.CountIf(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("NIMS dump-SC level").Range("B1:B" & NIMsRow), .Cells(l, 2).Value) Then
            .Cells(l, AudLastCol + 1).Value = Cells(l, AudLastCol + 1).Value & "Present in NIMS Dump."
        End If
    Next l
End With
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True    
End Sub
```

Comment: How do you know this snippet is the bottleneck? How long does it take right now?

Comment: I debugged different snippets of the code to find it out. My rest of the code which is used to develop this audit sheet from multiple workbooks takes around 10 mins and this one -analysis sheet takes 30-40 mins for 70,000 rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic is probably the biggest factor here. Using your estimate of 70,000 rows and assuming that `aPRTS` and `bNIMS` are equal for all of them, then you are doing around 420,000 `Match` calculations and an even greater number of accesses to cells (with all the overheads these have in comparison to array calculations).

### Use of Match

From what I can work out from the convoluted logic, you are using the `Match` merely to determine which columns you must compare. However, once you are in your worksheet, this column order does not change.

So, you can remove nearly half a million expensive calculations by doing this up front. For you logic, this is a good place to use a `Variant`.

```
With wsa
    AudLastCol = .Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    AudLastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    ' *** Do these next lines only once, not 70,000 times.
    Deployed19 = Application.Match("Deployed(1.9)", .Rows(1), 0)
    Deployed800 = Application.Match("Deployed (800)", .Rows(1), 0)
    Deployed2500 = Application.Match("Deployed (2.5)", .Rows(1), 0)
    PRTS1900 = Application.Match("Total-1900-PRTS", .Rows(1), 0)
    PRTS800 = Application.Match("Total-800-PRTS", .Rows(1), 0)
    PRTS2500 = Application.Match("Total-2500-PRTS", .Rows(1), 0)
    .Cells(1, AudLastCol + 1).Value = "Match;Issue Type;Actions"
    For l = 2 To AudLastRow
        aPRTS = .Cells(l, AudLastCol).Value
        bNIMS = .Cells(l, NIMsLastCol).Value
'        tempin = .Cells(l, 2).Value
        If aPRTS = bNIMS Then
            If IsNumeric(Deployed19) Then
                d19 = .Cells(l, Deployed19).Value
            Else
                d19 = 0
            End If
            If IsNumeric(Deployed800) Then
                d8 = .Cells(l, Deployed800).Value
            Else
                d8 = 0
            End If
            If IsNumeric(Deployed2500) Then
                d25 = .Cells(l, Deployed2500).Value
            Else
                d25 = 0
            End If

            If IsNumeric(PRTS800) Then
                p8 = .Cells(l, PRTS800).Value
            Else
                p8 = 0
            End If

            If IsNumeric(PRTS1900) Then
                p19 = .Cells(l, PRTS1900).Value
            Else
                p19 = 0
            End If

            If IsNumeric(PRTS2500) Then
                p25 = .Cells(l, PRTS2500).Value
            Else
                p25 = 0
            End If
            If (p19 = d19) And (p8 = d8) And (p25 = d25) Then
                .Cells(l, AudLastCol + 1).Value = "TRUE;None;No Action Required."
            Else
                .Cells(l, AudLastCol + 1).Value = "FALSE;Both;Update NIMS and PRTS."
            End If
        '[ELSEIF] statements here.
        End If
' [Other code here]
    Next l
End With
```

I have stuck with `Variant` because the `Match` might return an error. I have also left the standard `If-Then-Else` construct because the VBA `IIF()` statement evaluates all expressions so would return and error should the desired column not exist.

### Variable declaration

Your code to declare the variables is not doing what you think it should.

```
Dim wsa As Worksheet
Dim l, AudLastRow, AudLastCol, NIMsLastCol, NIMsRow As Long
Dim d19, d8, d25, p19, p8, p25 As Integer
Dim ColLtr As String
Dim aPRTS, bNIMS, Deployed19, Deployed800, Deployed2500, PRTS800, PRTS1900, PRTS2500 As Variant
```

Only `NIMsRow` is `Long`, `p25` is `Integer`, the rest are `Variant` which is the default type. Each variable must be individually declared as shown below. Also, while possibly not important for your dataset, get in the habit of using `Long` instead of `Integer`. Memory is cheap these days!

```
Dim wsa As Worksheet
Dim l As Long, AudLastRow As Long, AudLastCol As Long, NIMsLastCol As Long, NIMsRow As Long
Dim d19 As Long, d8 As Long, d25 As Long, p19 As Long, p8 As Long, p25 As Long
Dim ColLtr As String
Dim aPRTS, bNIMS, Deployed19, Deployed800, Deployed2500, PRTS800, PRTS1900, PRTS2500 'As Variant
```

### Use Arrays

It is faster to dump the data into arrays and then run through the arrays than to keep on referencing cells. Because you have blank cells in your data, you would use a `Variant` type and your code would check accordingly while doing comparisons. You can put the results of the audit into another array and then simple write this array in one hit at the end of your routine.

I am not going to write sample code here. But where you do an early check for the existence of a column (your `Match` functions), you can quickly create an array of `0` if it does not exist. This also simplify your `If aPRTS = bNIMS Then` block because you will not need all those `If-Then-Else`.

What arrays would you need?

- `aPRTS` and `bNIMS`: replaces/fixes `If aPRTS = bNIMS Then` etc
- `d19` and `p19`: replaces/fixes `If (p19 = d19) And (p8 = d8) And (p25 = d25) Then`
- `d8` and `p8`: replaces/fixes `If (p19 = d19) And (p8 = d8) And (p25 = d25) Then`
- `d25` and `p25`: replaces/fixes `If (p19 = d19) And (p8 = d8) And (p25 = d25) Then`
- `Name`: replaces/fixes `If InStr(1, .Cells(l, 1).Value, "52XC") > 0 Then` etc
- `AuditResult`: What you will write into the sheet at the end. fixes/replaces `.Cells(l, AudLastCol + 1).Value = "N/A;NIMS;Update NIMS."` etc.

Comment: Thanks AJD. I am not from a s/w engg background and have started learning programming 6 months back. 
The reason for this delay in my reply is I have been trying to understand the usage of arrays by reading about it from different sources online.
I did not understand how will I not need If-Then-else statements by using arrays. The way I understand arrays usage here is:instead of referencing the cell, I'll be saving the comments in an array and at the end, I'll populate that array data in cells using a for loop.
Can you please guide me with a reading source to understand arrays this way?

Comment: @SABU: An internet search will provide many references. Something like https://bettersolutions.com/excel/cells-ranges/vba-working-with-arrays.htm will be easy to understand. For more indepth analysis, there is always Chip Pearson's work: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/vbaarrays.htm and http://www.cpearson.com/excel/PassingAndReturningArrays.htm .

Comment: @SABU: What I was inferring by the use of arrays is that you can create a 0-filled array if a column does not exist (which is what your `If-Then` are doing). So, if you already know the array exists and is filled with 0, you can save time and effort in the coding. But yes, otherwise you would fill the array and in the end you will use a populated array of data to fill cells. However (to your benefit), you can fill a range without using a loop - another saving on time and effort!